# RX-JS 5 - Using "lift" to log Observable data for debugging

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I am new to RX-JS , and would like to log data for debugging purpose.
In the end what i need is to log every observable defined in piece of code and all events / emits of data happening out of those observables.

For RX-JS If i override **lift** , it becomes possible to inject behaviors into all observers in an operator chain ,
**But how can i log RX-Observables those are not applied to any operator yet ?**.

And is it proper way to log all observables to override **lift** and subscribe to each observables for logging data ,
Because **do** operator did not work.

This is how i am trying

```
const _lift = Rx.Observable.prototype.lift;
var idCounter = 0;
Rx.Observable.prototype.lift = function (operator) {
    var sourceObs = this ;
    sourceObs.id = ++idCounter;
    var resultantObservable = _lift.call(sourceObs, operator);
    resultantObservable.id = ++idCounter;
    // In this Method i log data 
    LogObserver(operator , sourceObs , resultantObservable);
    return resultantObservable;
};
```

Above code works for

```
var timer = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(4);
```

But does not work for

```
var sequence = Rx.Observable.range(1, 10);
```

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I get what you are trying to do but the way you are doing it is a little weird. I don't know if you've heard about the .let operator yet. 
If you do:

```
const subscribe = source
  .map(val => val + 1)
  .let(obs => {
     // do stuff with the observable here and return it afterwards
     // to not break the chain
     return obs;
  });

  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Let will give you access to the observable entirely, not just the values in it. You can do what you want to do with it. You need to return an observable in the let function but if you just do what you want and then return the original. You will not break the chain and you can do what you want I guess.

More info here: https://github.com/btroncone/learn-rxjs/blob/master/operators/utility/let.md

Comment: thanks for reply .    I would like to debug any piece of RX-JS code without modifiyng the code itself. That's why looking for some RX-JS interface / Override part of RX-JS to sniff/log every event. I hope now it is more clear ? I am trying to develop something like this http://jaredforsyth.com/rxvision/examples/playground/